# AnimatedVisibility is not working with weights

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation, android-jetpack-compose-animation

Here is a simple example to reproduce the issue I'm having:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedVisibilityEx(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .border(width = 2.dp, color = Color.Blue, shape = CircleShape)
            )

            AnimatedVisibility(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                visible = visible
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                )
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .border(width = 2.dp, color = Color.Red, shape = CircleShape)
            )

            Button(
                onClick = { visible = !visible },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 32.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Toggle Visible")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 boxes with equal weights. The middle one is going away on button click and I want a nice animation - the middle one shrinks and the other 2 expand to equally take up the space.
However, there is no animation running. When I remove the weights and give them heights then everything works fine. What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try my answer. Does it work for you.?

Comment: It doesn't fit my needs since not all elements in column have weight

Comment: Need not have weights for all elements in column

Comment: Its only the width of the box is eithe availableWidth/3 when you toogle its availableWidth/2 as you can see in the answer

Comment: Your solution is replacing weights with calculated sizes. Imagine one of the boxes is a Text composable without a weight modifier, and its size is defined by the text itself, so it is dynamic. Then I have 2 boxes with weights. One of the boxes should be hidden. How would you calculate the width of the remaining box without knowing the width of the text? The beauty of weights is that compose will calculate the size of the Text and then give the rest of the space to the boxes according to their weights.

Comment: you could measure the text also. i have deleted my answer for now!

Comment: I added my answer based on the comment where we measure the text width and set the width of the remaining boxes based on the text width + the padding you require for the text itself

Answer (score 0):

An ugly workaround is to remove the `AnimatedVisibility` and animate the weight instead:

```
...

    val animatedWeight: Float by animateFloatAsState(if (visible) 1f else 0.000001f)

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(animatedWeight)
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
    )

...
```

This, of course, will not allow you to use the rich set of enter/exit animations that `AnimatedVisibility` provides.

Answer (score 0):

How about using BoxWithConstraints?.

```
@Composable
fun BoxAnim() {
    var middleBoxVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Column {
        BoxWithConstraints {
            val middleBoxWidth = if (middleBoxVisible) maxWidth / 3 else 0.dp
            val sideBoxWidth = (maxWidth - middleBoxWidth) / 2

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(sideBoxWidth)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )

                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = middleBoxVisible,
                    enter = slideInHorizontally() + expandHorizontally(),
                    exit = shrinkHorizontally() + slideOutHorizontally()
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(middleBoxWidth)
                            .height(100.dp)
                            .background(Color.Green)
                    )
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(sideBoxWidth)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
            }
        }

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(80.dp),
            onClick = { middleBoxVisible = !middleBoxVisible }) {
            Text(text = "Toggle Middle Box")
        }
    }
    
}
```

The BoxWithConstraints composable is used to get the maximum width of the screen. We want to show 3 boxes equally on screen so maxWidth/3 for each of them. In case the middle is not visible we recalculate the width of the other two boxes maxWidth/2.

Update 2: Based on the comment we can measure text width and then decide the width of the middle box

```
@Composable
fun BoxAnim2() {
    var middleBoxVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    var middleBoxText by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World! Raghunandan") } // Initial text

    val textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current

    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val textMeasured = remember(textStyle, textMeasurer) {
        textMeasurer.measure(
            text = middleBoxText,
            style = textStyle.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        ).size.width
    }

    val newWidth = with(LocalDensity.current) { textMeasured.toDp() + 8.dp }

    Column {
        BoxWithConstraints {

            val middleBoxWidth = if (middleBoxVisible) newWidth else 0.dp
            val sideBoxWidth = ((maxWidth) - middleBoxWidth) / 2

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(sideBoxWidth)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )

                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = middleBoxVisible,
                    enter =  expandHorizontally(),
                    exit = shrinkHorizontally() 
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .wrapContentWidth()
                            .height(100.dp)
                            .background(Color.Green)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            maxLines =  1,
                            text = middleBoxText,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(sideBoxWidth)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
            }
        }

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(80.dp),
            onClick = { middleBoxVisible = !middleBoxVisible }) {
            Text(text = "Toggle Middle Box")
        }
    }

}
```